# Передать переменную JS в PHP в WordPress

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Вот код JS

```
$('.pages_list a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var postId = parseInt( $(this).attr('data-catid') );
    postviewCountGet(postId);
});

function postviewCountGet(postId){
    $( ".text" ).load( "<? echo bloginfo('template_url') . '/posts.php'?>" );
};
```

Вот posts.php

```
   <?php
     echo $postId;
   ?>
```

Как в WordPress переменную js var postId  передать в переменную php $postId без перезагрузки страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы передавать данные или делать запроса на сервер без перезагрузки страницы и форм вам понадобится AJAX.

Вот к примеру:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "variable=" + postId,
  success: function(msg){
    alert( "Прибыли данные: " + msg );
  }
});
```

```php
<?php

$postId = (isset($_REQUEST)) ? $_REQUEST : null;
```

А подробнее о AJAX тут http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: А что должно быть в url: ?

Comment: $postId равна пустому массиву. А msg в консоли выводит весь html документа.

Comment: @Denis, в URL должно указываться ссылка на исполняемый файл, а в Data данные. Переменная msg равна тому что отправляет сервер, т. е. исполняемый файл, и вообще success не обязательный. А сама реализация метода зависит от того что вы хотите сделать, что получать и для чего.

Comment: Выдает   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 POST http://hitechbuld/some.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Denis, по какому пути находится исполняемый файл которому нужно передать переменную?

Comment: <? echo bloginfo('template_url') . '/posts.php'; ?>

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно передать переменную в posts.php. Потом в posts.php циклом создается массив карточек постов. и этот уже массив карточек мне нужно передать в $( ".text" ) который на странице откуда начинался запрос.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jqhTE0Xj

Comment: Так и пытался сделать. Спасибо. Вот новый пост создал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/961351/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA